# Why does ethanol decrease viscosity of a high pH carbomer solution more compared to water

Tags: organic-chemistry, solutions, polymers

Carbomer 407 is made up of acrylic acid that undergoes polymerisation to form a long linear structure. At higher pH, the carboxylic acid functional groups will dissociate to form carboxylate ions. These carboxylate ions will have a strong electrostatic forces of repulsion that gives them its high viscosity.

When adding a water and ethanol to a high pH solution of carbomer, both the viscosity decreases but it is more significant in ethanol. Why?

Comment: Include a short summary of what you  already know or have found in offline and online resources. If nothing was found, write at least what a/o where you have searched. 
This way responders avoid duplication of your effort and redundancy of internet content.

Comment: Review the guide [How to ask](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Asking FAQs](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to prevent clarification requests, objections,  down-voting or closure.

Comment: Water would create much stronger intermolecular hydrogen bond than ethanol. $\ce{\bond{-}CO-O^{-}\bond{...}H-O-H\bond{...}O^{-}-CO\bond{-}}$